# PHP while loop (mysql_fetch_array) only displaying last record from table

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

This is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

$contactID=$row['contactID'];
$contactFamily =$row ['contactFamily'];
$Contact=$row ['Contact'];
$contactOwner =$row ['contactOwner'];
$Impact=$row ['Impact'];
$Probability =$row ['Probability'];



if ($row ['Impact']=="5" && $row['Probability']=="4")
{
    $grid1=  $row ['contactFamily']." ".$row ['Contact']." .$row['contactOwner'];
}

?>
<br/>
<?php

if ($row ['Impact']=="3" && $row['Probability']=="4")
{
    $grid2=  $row ['contactFamily']." ".$row ['Contact']." .$row['contactOwner'];
}
?>
<br/>
<?

}
```

The problem is that it is only displaying the last record in the table when I echo $grid1 or $grid2 rather than all of them.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: they're not arrays, so when you assign new values to them, they overwrite the last value

Answer (score 0):

`$grid1` and `$grid2` need to be an arrays. Otherwise you're just overwriting your value each time you go through the loop.

```
$grid1 = array();
$grid2 = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

$grid1[] =  $row ['contactFamily']." ".$row ['Contact']." ".$row['contactOwner'];

$grid2[] =  $row ['contactFamily']." ".$row ['Contact']." ".$row['contactOwner'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should echo $grid1 and $grid2 inside the while loop as each time the loop runs, they are overwritten by the next value.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you iterate over the results set you are re-assigning `$grid1` and `$grid2` with the string you are creating, which is why only the last result is being displayed. What you want to do is use the concatenating assignment operator `.=` e.g.

```
$grid1 .= $row['contactFamily']." ".$row['Contact']." ".$row['contactOwner'];
```

Comment: This has fixed the problem fine but now I am getting undefined variable notices for $grid1 and $grid2.

Answer (score 0):

You are filling a variable multiple times but it only keeps the last value, that's the reason you always see the last value. I've changed your code using arrays:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$i = 0
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$i]['contactID'] = $row['contactID'];
    $data[$i]['contactFamily'] = $row['contactFamily'];
    $data[$i]['Contact'] =$row['Contact'];
    $data[$i]['contactOwner'] = $row['contactOwner'];
    $data[$i]['Impact'] = $row['Impact'];
    $data[$i]['Probability'] = $row['Probability'];

    if ($row['Impact'] == "5" && $row['Probability'] =="4") {
        $grid1[$i] = $row['contactFamily'] . " " . $row ['Contact'] . " " . $row['contactOwner'];
    }
    if ($row['Impact']=="3" && $row['Probability']=="4") {
        $grid2[$i] = $row['contactFamily'] . " " . $row ['Contact'] . " " . $row['contactOwner'];
    }
    $i++;
}
```